# how to select one table then join another table mysql

Tags: mysql

so i have two tables.

**users**

```
users_id   |   firstname    |  lastname
10001      |      mike      |    lapiz
10002      |      tom       |    jerry
```

**profile**

```
profile_id   |   department   |   specialization
10001        |    Health Dept |     Heart
10002        |   Brain Dept   |     Brain
```

maybe you're curious why i separate the name of the user and the profile.. i have my on reasons for that.. what i wanted to do is to select my all fields from `profile` then join the `users` table

what i want to be the result is

```
users_id | firstname   |  lastname | profile_id  | department   |specialization
10001    |  mike       |   lapiz   |  1001       |  health dept |   heart
```

this is my query..

```
$sql = SELECT a.profile_id,a.department,a.specialization FROM `tbl_profile` AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT users_id,firstname,lastname FROM `tbl_users`) AS b ON a.profile_id = b.users_id
```

what happen is it only display the profile table.. it is not displaying the other table.. and when i tried to

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.users_id,b.firstname,b.lastname FROM `tbl_users`) AS b
```

it give me an error unknown column `b.users_id`

Comment: The `profile` table needs a `user_id` column which will be a foreign key referring the corresponding user row in the `user` table.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: That would establish a 1:{0;n} relation, wheras the OP obviously wants it to be 1:{0;1}. So `profile.profile_id` is supposedly both the table's primary key and a foreign key to `users.user_id`, which establishes the relation correctly.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I appreciate your reply. Bad db design though.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: Not necessarily. One reason for such a design can be user rights (all users can access the users table, but only few are allowed the profiles table). Another could be consistency: Either a user has no profile yet or a profile with all mandatory fields filled.

Comment: Years later that I am reading this again now, I'd like to add that it is indeed a very bad idea of course to name a user ID profile_id. Aluan Haddad was right in this point. A profile is not a user (even when it's 1:1 related), so the name is misleading and should be changed in the data model.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how a join works.

```
FROM tbl_profile JOIN tbl_users ON ...
```

joins the two tables, i.e. combines records on the given condition in ON.

```
FROM tbl_profile JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_users)
```

does exactly the same. It makes no difference if you join a table directly or join the records of the table, because this means exactly the same.

```
FROM tbl_profile JOIN (SELECT users_id, firstname, lastname FROM tbl_users)
```

again does the very same thing. Only that you restrict the columns you can use in the query to the three stated columns. So if there existed more columns in the table, you could not use them in the query's select or where or order by clause anymore.

So a join means just combining records. Which columns you want to show, you put in the select clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profile JOIN tbl_users ON ...
```

selects all columns from both tables.

```
SELECT p.department FROM tbl_profile p JOIN tbl_users u ON ...
```

selects only the department.

You want:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users u JOIN tbl_profile p ON p.profile_id = u.user_id
```

A LEFT JOIN by the way is **an outer join** where you keep the records from the left table in your results even when there is no match in the right table. In your query you said that you wanted to show profile records too that have no match in the users table, which was certainly not intended.

Answer (score 1):

You should use inner join not nested inner join

```
    $sql = SELECT a.profile_id,a.department,a.specialization,b.users_id,b.firstname,
           b.lastname FROM tbl_profile AS a  inner join tbl_users b
           ON a.profile_id = b.users_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to list all the columns in both the tables with LEFT OUTER JOIN, the following query will serve your purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN profile on users.users_id = profile.profile_id
```

You can use the alias as well if you want as following:

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN profile p on u.users_id = p.profile_id
```